# rails + rspec: error duplicate or already exists "as:" routes, but I haven't any duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have next error, but I haven't any duplicate "as:" routes and have the same error with "mount"

Version: 
  Rails 5.0-stable
  rspec 3.7

ArgumentError:
  Invalid route name, already in use: 'api_base' 
  You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with `resources` as explained here: 
  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created

Routes:

```
                                                 Prefix Verb     URI Pattern                                                                                                Controller#Action
                                           api_base          /                                                                                                          API::Base
                                grape_swagger_rails          /documentation                                                                                             GrapeSwaggerRails::Engine
                                promo_change_status POST     /promos/:promo_id/change_status(.:format)                                                                  promos#change_status
                                 promos_here_promos GET      /promos/promos_here(.:format)                                                                              promos#promos_here
                                             promos GET      /promos(.:format)                                                                                          promos#index
                                                    POST     /promos(.:format)                                                                                          promos#create
                                          new_promo GET      /promos/new(.:format)                                                                                      promos#new
                                         edit_promo GET      /promos/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                                 promos#edit
                                              promo GET      /promos/:id(.:format)                                                                                      promos#show
                                                    PATCH    /promos/:id(.:format)                                                                                      promos#update
                                                    PUT      /promos/:id(.:format)                                                                                      promos#update
                                                    DELETE   /promos/:id(.:format)                                                                                      promos#destroy
```

routes.rb file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
mount API::Base => '/' 
mount GrapeSwaggerRails::Engine, at: "/documentation"

resources :promos do
  post 'change_status', to: 'promos#change_status', as: 'change_status'

  collection do
     get 'promos_here', action: 'promos_here'
   end 
end
```

end

any idea?

Thank!

Comment: Run `bundle exec rails routes` and paste in your question the output.

Comment: Can’t help without any info. I’d suspect a duplicate route, despite your assertion to the contrary.

Comment: yes, I share the routes but there aren't duplicates..

Comment: Please show your `config/routes.rb`.

Comment: What has this question got to do with `rspec`? The problem almost certainly lies in `config/routes.rb` (can you please show us this file?) If you *have* done something unusual with route (re)definition in the specs, then can you show the source of the error?

Comment: Yes @TomLord  the error only generate with rspec

Comment: I don't know what is wrong, any idea?